# Is it possible to rotate text displayed on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have some code where a graph is displayed for the user, and under the x-axis there is some text which describes that point. The problem I've encountered is that the words overlap each other when displayed. The text can't be small. I thought it would be good if the text was flipped 90° to the right so that they won't overlap.

This is the code I have to labelling the graph;

```
  for i in range(points2):
        z.create_text(i*intervalSpacing+50,260,fill="darkblue",font= "4",
                      text=times[i])
```

Is there anything that allows the text to be rotated?

Comment: As you noticed, `create_text` has no `angle` option.  Can you vertically offset horizontal labels so they don't overlap?  You might be able to place single (unrotated) letters, each below the previous.  With a separate image program, such as `pillow`, you *might* be able to create a rotated image of text.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes it does. It's not documented, but it's there (since tcl 8.6, I'm told).

Comment: @bryan-oakley @dyz Can you un-mark this as duplicate? The duplicate answer you linked is out of date. Tk has since added an `-angle` option to `create_text`.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you.  I see that tk create_text now has -angle option, http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M156 and confirmed that it works *in tkinter*.  I also discovered `canvas.itemconfigure` and should have used it to check for something new in 8.6.