# How to launch a turtle program with a tkinter messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

I am trying to launch a turtle game stored in one file with a message box from `tkinter` stored in another py file but both in the same directory. However, I receive a
 `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist` error.

I have a function inside the game code that is called upon in the launcher code. This function runs all of the code inside the main game program apart from importing modules which I have included in the function but makes no difference.

Sorry for showing all but as I don't know what the problem is I thought this was best(removed as much code irrelevant to problem as I could(Assume anything unnamed that is called is deleted as irrelevant code)

```
def start():
    import turtle
    import math
    import time

    counter = 0

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.setup(800, 600)

    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.title("Trooper shooter")
    wn.bgpic("background1.png")
    wn.update()

    turtle.register_shape("invader.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("plane.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("troop.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("player1.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("player2.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("bomb.gif")
    turtle.register_shape("boom.gif")

    #player
    soldier = turtle.Turtle()
    soldier.color("blue")
    soldier.shape("player1.gif")
    soldier.penup()
    soldier.speed(0)
    soldier.setposition(0,-200)
    soldier.setheading(90)
    soldierspd = 20

    #Bomb

    Numbombs = 2
    bombs = []
    for i in range(Numbombs):
        bombs.append(turtle.Turtle())
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.shape("bomb.gif")
        bomb.penup()
        bomb.speed(0)
        bomb.ht()
        x = -1700

        y = 2700
        bomb.setposition(x+30,y)
        bomb.setheading(270)
    bombspeed = 10

    #Plane
    plane = turtle.Turtle()
    plane.color("red")
    plane.shape("plane.gif")
    plane.penup()
    plane.speed(0)
    plane.setposition(-270,200)
    plane.setheading(360)
    planespd = 20

    #Plane2
    plane2 = turtle.Turtle()
    plane2.ht()
    plane2.color("red")
    plane2.shape("plane.gif")
    plane2.penup()
    plane2.speed(0)
    plane2.setposition(-270,200)
    plane2.setheading(360)
    planespd2 = 20

    #ParaTroopers
    num = 5
    Troopers = []

    for i in range(num):
        Troopers.append(turtle.Turtle())

    for Troop in Troopers:
        Troop.color("Purple")
        Troop.shape("troop.gif")
        Troop.penup()
        Troop.speed(0)
        Troop.ht()
        x = -170
        y = 270
        Troop.setposition(x+30,y)
        Troop.setheading(270)
    Troopspeed = 3

    #Bullet
    bullet = turtle.Turtle()
    bullet.color("yellow")
    bullet.shape("triangle")
    bullet.penup()
    bullet.speed(0)
    bullet.setheading(90)
    bullet.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
    bullet.ht()

    bulletspeed = 30

    #Define bullet state
    #ready = ready to fire
    #fire = bullet is firing
    state = "ready"

    #Move player left
    def Left():
        x = soldier.xcor()
        x -= soldierspd
        soldier.setx(x)
        soldier.shape("player1.gif")
        if x < -280:
            x = -280
            soldier.setx(x)


    #Move player right
    def Right():
        x = soldier.xcor()
        x += soldierspd
        soldier.setx(x)
        soldier.shape("player2.gif")
        if x > 280:
            x = 280
            soldier.setx(x)
    #Shoot bullet

    def Shoot():
        #Declare bullet state as global
        global state
        if state == "ready":
            state = "fire"
            #Move bullet above player
            x = soldier.xcor()
            y = soldier.ycor()
            bullet.setposition(x, y +10)
            bullet.showturtle()

    #HitBoxes
    def checkCollision(A,B):
        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(A.xcor() - B.xcor(), 2) +
        math.pow(A.ycor() - B.ycor(), 2))
        if distance < 30:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    #Move plane
    def MovePlane():

        x = plane.xcor()
        x += planespd
        plane.speed(1)
        plane.setx(x)
        if plane.xcor() > 280:
            plane.ht()

    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(Left,"Left")
    turtle.onkey(Right,"Right")
    turtle.onkey(Shoot,"space")


    while True:
        #Move Plane
        MovePlane()

        #Move count
        incCount()



        #Show Paratrooper
        x = -200
        for Troop in Troopers:
            if plane.xcor() > x+50:
                x += 80
                Troop.setx(x)
                Troop.showturtle()
                y = Troop.ycor()
                y -= Troopspeed
                Troop.sety(y)
                if y < -280:
                    Troop.ht()

            if checkCollision(bullet, Troop):
                # Reset bullet
                bullet.ht()
                state = "ready"
                bullet.setposition(0, -400)
                Troop.shape("boom.gif")
                # Update Scoreboard
                score += 10
                scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
                score_pen.clear()
                score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
                time.sleep(0.1)
                Troop.setposition(1000, 1000)

        #update background
        if counter == 30:
            wn.bgpic("background2.png")
            wn.update()
        if counter == 60:
            wn.bgpic("background3.png")
            wn.update()
        if counter == 90:
            wn.bgpic("background4.png")
            wn.update()
        if counter == 120:
            wn.bgpic("background5.png")
            wn.update()
        if counter == 150:
            wn.bgpic("background6.png")
            wn.update()


    wn.mainloop()
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import TrooperShooter



root = Tk()
launch = messagebox.askquestion("launcher","Play game?")
if launch == "yes":
    TrooperShooter.start()
```

When the launcher is run a messagebox should appear saying do you wish to play
 and when "yes" is clicked the function to start the game is launched. However I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Trooper shooter/launcher.py", line 10, in <module>
    TrooperShooter.start()
  File "C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Trooper shooter\TrooperShooter.py", line 18, in start
    wn.bgpic("background1.png")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1482, in bgpic
    self._setbgpic(self._bgpic, self._bgpics[picname])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 738, in _setbgpic
    self.cv.itemconfig(item, image=image)
  File "<string>", line 1, in itemconfig
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2578, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It looks like the error is at `wn.bgpic("background1.png")`. Does this file not exist within the folder?

Comment: Have you tried commenting just this line out to verify it works and this line is the only issue?

Comment: has to be something to do with the images not being recognised with the 2nd tkinter program.

Comment: I disagree. If `player1.gif` is the next error that means it loaded `invader.gif`, `plane.gif`, and `troop.gif` without error. How is `player1.gif` different than these?

Comment: my mistake the registration is fine but when the image is called thats the problme

Comment: It doesnt need to work this exact way i just need a way to run this program through tkinter. Would putting the launcher in the same program help?

Comment: Typically I prefer to code an entire project in a single file because you can "tuck away" entire functions and classes in my IDE (PyCharm) so scrolling the entire program is still very quick. With such a short program I don't personally see why you feel the need to separate them into different files. I can post a method to combine them into one, but can't guarantee it will work because I can't test it myself (I don't have the images)

Comment: Wait I just noticed that your `wn.mainloop()` is unreachable... You call it after a `while True:` loop that has no `break`'s.

Comment: where should the wn.mainloop() go then? I dont think it'll help as that just creates the screen but that is already made.

Comment: Can i provide you with the images. This is the code for my Alevel project so i need this to work but ive still got over a year to finish it.

Comment: the `turtle` module is itself implemented using `tkinter`, so it possible to that trying to use it in a script that's also doing so conflicts. Consider putting all the game code into a separate standalone script and executing that from the main script (via the `subprocess` module).

Comment: not sure i quite understand, could u provide an example or how mine would be written?

Comment: If it is a turtle vs. tkinter error you could try spawning the turtle as a new process. Docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class Essentially you would change `TrooperShooter.start()` to `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=TrooperShooter.start)`;`p.start()`

Comment: Sorry, but fixing you current code, which is what they call "procedural", would be too much work since that kind of coding isn't compatible with using `tkinter`, which is what is called "user event-driven" — i.e. everything has to happen while the tkinter `mainloop()` is running. A concrete example is the `while True:` infinite loop you have which prevents the `wn.mainloop()` from even being executed.

Comment: if theres no way to fix this, is there a way to essentially create the same game but using tkinter alone and not turtle? this would surely have no problem and the code photoimage would work?

Comment: or could a completely different userinterface be made using turtle sprites like buttons to complete a function if they are clicked to launch the program instead?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is that you use the turtle `textinput()` method (new in Python 3) instead of dragging tkinter and messagebox into the picture.

But if you're going to combine tkinter and turtle, you need to do it correctly.  Turtle is designed to run either *standalone* with its own Tk window or *embedded* in an existing tkinter window.  You're attempting to run it standalone, embedded in a tkinter window.  I.e. instead of the standalone `Turtle` & `Screen` interface, you should be working with the embedded `TurtleScreen`, `RawTurtle` and `ScrolledCanvas` interface.

Besides this issue, your code is generally buggy.  You've lots of unfinished code.  Your use of `global` has to become `nonlocal` when you move the entire program inside the `start()` function.  You're missing pieces of code necessary to run.  Finally, you have a `while True:` loop which has no business being in an event-driven environment like turtle.  I've repaced it with a timer event.

I've reworked your code below to run as you intended.  I've tossed incomplete and/or broken features to simplify the example.  The startup code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import TrooperShooter

root = Tk()

launch = messagebox.askquestion("launcher", "Play game?")

if launch == "yes":

    TrooperShooter.start(root)
```

TrooperShooter.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas, RawTurtle

def start(root):

    # Move player left
    def Left():
        soldier.shape("player1.gif")

        x = soldier.xcor() - soldierspd
        soldier.setx(x)

        if x < -280:
            soldier.setx(-280)

    # Move player right
    def Right():
        soldier.shape("player2.gif")

        x = soldier.xcor() + soldierspd
        soldier.setx(x)

        if x > 280:
            soldier.setx(280)

    # Shoot bullet
    def Shoot():
        # Declare bullet state as global
        nonlocal state

        if state == "ready":
            state = "fire"
            # Move bullet above player
            x, y = soldier.position()
            bullet.setposition(x, y + 10)
            bullet.showturtle()

    # HitBoxes
    def checkCollision(a, b):
        return a.distance(b) < 30

    # Move plane
    def MovePlane():
        x = plane.xcor() + plane_speed
        plane.setx(x)

        if plane.xcor() > 280:
            plane.hideturtle()

    def action():
        nonlocal state, score

        # Move Plane
        MovePlane()

        # Show Paratrooper
        x = -200
        for troop in troopers:
            if plane.xcor() > x + 50:
                x += 80
                troop.setx(x)
                troop.showturtle()
                y = troop.ycor() - troop_speed
                troop.sety(y)
                if y < -280:
                    troop.hideturtle()

            if checkCollision(bullet, troop):
                # Reset bullet
                bullet.hideturtle()
                state = "ready"
                bullet.setposition(0, -400)
                troop.shape("boom.gif")
                # Update Scoreboard
                score += 10
                scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
                score_pen.clear()
                score_pen.write(scorestring, align="left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
                troop.setposition(1000, 1000)

        if state == "fire":
            y = bullet.ycor()

            if y > 300:
                state = 'ready'
                bullet.hideturtle()
            else:
                bullet.sety(y+ bullet_speed)

        screen.ontimer(action, 100)

    score = 0

    # Define bullet state
    # ready = ready to fire
    # fire = bullet is firing
    state = "ready"

    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.title("Trooper shooter")

    canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root)
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

    screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)

    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.bgpic("background1.png")

    screen.register_shape("invader.gif")
    screen.register_shape("plane.gif")
    screen.register_shape("troop.gif")
    screen.register_shape("player1.gif")
    screen.register_shape("player2.gif")
    screen.register_shape("boom.gif")

    # Player
    soldier = RawTurtle(screen)
    soldier.color("blue")
    soldier.shape("player1.gif")
    soldier.penup()
    soldier.speed('fastest')
    soldier.setposition(0, -200)
    soldier.setheading(90)
    soldierspd = 20

    # Score
    score_pen = RawTurtle(screen)
    score_pen.speed('fastest')
    score_pen.hideturtle()

    # Plane
    plane = RawTurtle(screen)
    plane.color("red")
    plane.shape("plane.gif")
    plane.penup()
    plane.speed('fastest')
    plane.setposition(-270, 200)
    plane.setheading(360)
    plane_speed = 20

    # ParaTroopers
    number_troops = 5
    troopers = []

    for _ in range(number_troops):
        troop = RawTurtle(screen)
        troop.color("Purple")
        troop.shape("troop.gif")
        troop.penup()
        troop.speed('fastest')
        troop.hideturtle()
        x, y = -170, 270
        troop.setposition(x + 30, y)
        troop.setheading(270)

        troopers.append(troop)

    troop_speed = 3

    # Bullet
    bullet = RawTurtle(screen)
    bullet.color("yellow")
    bullet.shape("triangle")
    bullet.penup()
    bullet.speed('fastest')
    bullet.setheading(90)
    bullet.shapesize(0.5)
    bullet.hideturtle()

    bullet_speed = 30

    screen.onkey(Left, "Left")
    screen.onkey(Right, "Right")
    screen.onkey(Shoot, "space")
    screen.listen()

    action()

    screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, Tk 8.6 [added built-in support for the `.png`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images) image file format. I tested it with Python 3.7.2 and it worked.

Comment: @martineau, thanks!  (Probably means we finally get rotated fonts too?)  I'll make a note and edit out that issue above.

Comment: @martineau, sigh.  Feel free to clean up after me next time!  ;-(

Comment: Hmm, I think Tk 8.6 can draw angled text on a `Canvas`, if that's what you mean (haven't tested this myself). See [Is it possible to rotate text displayed on a tkinter canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601143/is-it-possible-to-rotate-text-displayed-on-a-tkinter-canvas)

Comment: wow thanks so much for sorting through all my code! Its really given me hope to continue you with this and i appreciate all your effort. The reason some of my code is missing / incomplete is because I only uploaded code i thought was relevant to the problem at hand and wanted to shorten it.